# PUT file in drive API v3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-drive-api

So I've a dumb problem who is ruining my day so far.
I'm actually developing a React/Node app for fun. My goal is to manage a project from a unique dashboard.

I'm hoping to upload files to a google drive folder from this dashboard. So I worked on the thing with the help of the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/simple-upload

So far I can manage to upload files directly by hitting the endpoint with a POST method:

```
await Axios.post(`https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files`, file, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${data.accessToken}`,
    'Content-Type': file.type
  }
});
```

but problem comes when I try to update the file with the PUT method.

To explain quickly: 
I want each file that I upload to be uploaded to a specific folder on my drive. So I tought I'll make 2 calls, one to set the metadata on my API side:

[API side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiYnt.png)

And once it's done return the data to my client side to update the endpoint with the ID (and a put as mentionned in the documentation)

[Client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVTZn.png)

So my question is how to PUT on this upload endpoint ? Where do I specify the ID ?

If anyone knows it would be a great help !!!

Have an awesome day all of you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive API v3 uses PATCH rather than PUT. Change PUT to PATCH and things should work fine.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/#Files

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! It's working !! The documentation is pretty weird... Have a good day !